# when scrolling, stick Header at the top of the screen

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a **Gridview** with a lot of records inside. If you scroll down the **GridView** than the header doesnt stick to the top of the screen

**To fix this issue.** If you scroll down the **GridView**, than I am re-created a Header using (JS code). So If you scroll down than a new header **GHead** pops up at the top with same width as original header (**gridview**).

**Issue** - if you re-size the window, than the header doesnt align with the columns width. This is because, **GridView** width doesnt change on re-sizing window but **GHead** width will change if you re-size the window. In result **GHead** doesnt align with **GridView** columns. I dont wan tto change width of GHead when re-sizing window

[image]

JS Code - here I am getting gridview column width and re-creating using JS code

```
<script language="javascript" >
      $(document).ready(function () {
      var gridHeader = $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%>').clone(true); // Here Clone Copy of Gridview with style
      $(gridHeader).find("tr:gt(0)").remove(); // Here remove all rows except first row (header row)
      $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%> tr th').each(function (i) {
          // Here Set Width of each th from gridview to new table(clone table) th 
          $("th:nth-child(" + (i + 1) + ")", gridHeader).css('width', ($(this).width() + 5).toString() + "px");
      });
      $("#GHead").append(gridHeader);

      $('#container').css('position', 'relative');
      $('#GHead').css('position', 'fixed');
      $('#GHead').css('width', $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%>').width());
      $('#GHead').css('top', $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%>').offset().top);
      //$('#GHead').css('top', $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%>').offset().top);

  });

  // if you scroll down than JS header will pop up at the top of the screen
  $(document).scroll(function () {
      var y = $(this).scrollTop();
      if (y > 700) {
          $('#GHead').fadeIn();
      } else {
          $('#GHead').fadeOut();

      }
  });
</script>
```

html code - here i have a GridView with some columns inside it

```
<div id="container" style="width:auto">
    <div id="GHead" style="z-index:2000; "></div> 

         <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" ....>
              ....
         </asp:GridView>
     </div>
```

Comment: hey Dan, sorry you were disappointed with the response to your (now deleted) listagg question.  just want to make sure you know there are plenty of helpful people out there that will look at your question, and some less helpful.  obviously if you can spend a little time presenting info so people can repro exactly what you are seeing, that gets you much faster response, but even without that you are likely to get help given more time.  that said, you really do have to identify which database system you are using to get the right people looking at your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no need to use JavaScript. You can easily implement this using CSS position property `sticky`.

This is an example

```html
<div>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
    </div>
    <div style="position: relative;">
      <div style="position: sticky; top: 0; background: black; color: white;">
        Grid Head
      </div>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
      <p>hello world</p>
    </div>
```